# Why physical host nic can't be used in KVM

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

Why bridged networking is required for guest vm's in KVM ? 
Why we can't use the host nic to provide networking for guests.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a virtual machine.  That means it doesn't have access to the real hardware.  Thus qemu must create a virtual nic in the vm and ferry the packets to the real nic.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a way to directly attach a physical network card to a kvm/qemu, but I am of no help with this. IMHO, there is a way to attach any or almost any physical pci and usb device to the kvm/qemu vm.